# Python unittest.main() unable to instantiate inner classes

Tags: python, python-unittest

When I run the following test case using unittest.main():

```
import unittest

class TestInner_Helper(unittest.TestCase):

    class InnerClass(object):
        def __init__(self):
            self.flag_var = False

        def setFlag(self, newVal):
            self.flag_var = newVal

    def test_inner_class(self):
        inner = InnerClass()
        self.assertFalse(inner.flag_var)
        inner.setFlag(True)
        self.assertTrue(inner.flag_var)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_inner_class.py", line 13, in test_inner_class
    inner = InnerClass()
NameError: global name 'InnerClass' is not defined
```

Why is the test runner unable to instantiate the inner class? I'm running this on Python 2.7.14 on OSX.

Comment: `inner = self.InnerClass()` will work as the inner class is a class attribute of the outer class and should be accessed as such: `inner = TestInner_Helper.InnerClass()` is even clearer.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Could you put that in an answer so I can mark it as such (and give you the points you deserve)?

Comment: I can't, the question is closed already (I have voted to close it myself), so no more answers are possible. Nevermind ;)